# invalid or incomplete html syntax issue

Tags: html, css

when you find the "hard" stuff easy and the easy stuff hard!

Not sure why I'm asking for help with what looks like a very simple html and/or css problem but here I am.

Please see screenshot for a visual on the problem. My electronics seem  to be all over the place even though i've checked by divs and html syntax, that also goes for my footer. The css i believe is correct but perhaps i'm missing a div somewhere. I need a fresh pair of eyes to see something I clearly don't.

so i've added my getItem function()

```js
function getItem(){
   global $con;
    
    //limit to just getting 6 random products per page
    $get_item = "select * from items order by RAND() LIMIT 0,6";
    $run_item = mysqli_query($con,$get_item);
    
    //using while loop to get multiple data from items table
    
    while($row_item = mysqli_fetch_array($run_item)){
        
        $item_id = $row_item['item_id'];
        $item_cat = $row_item['item_cat'];
        $item_brand = $row_item['item_brand'];
        $item_title = $row_item['item_title'];
        $item_price = $row_item['item_price'];
        $item_image = $row_item['item_image'];
        
        
        
        echo "
    <div id='single_item'>
    
     <h3>$item_title</h3>
                    <img src='admin_area/item_imgs/$item_image'width=180' height='180'/>
     
            ";
    }
    
}





?>
```

[screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cr6G.png)

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}



body {background:skyblue;}



.wrapper_main{
width:1000px;
height:auto;
margin:auto;
background:black;
}

.wrapper_header{
width:1000px;
height:100px;
margin:auto;

}

#logo {float:left;}

#banner {float:right;}

.menubar {
width:1000px;
height:50px;
background:gray;
color:white;

}

#indexmenu {
padding:0;
margin:0;
line-height:40px;
float:left;
}

#indexmenu li {
list-style:none;
display:inline;
}

#indexmenu a {
text-decoration:none;
color:white;
padding:8px;
margin:5px;
font-size:18px;
font-family:COMIC SANS MS;
}

#indexmenu a:hover {color:orange; font-weight:bolder; text-decoration:underline;}

#form {float:right; padding-right:8px; line-height:50px;}

.content_wrapper {
width:1000px;
margin:auto;
background:pink;

}

#content_area {
width:800px;
float:right;
background:pink;
}

#sidebar {
width:200px;
background:black;
float:left;
}

#sidebar_title {
background:white;
color:black;
font-size:22px;
font-family:arial; 
padding:10px;
text-align:center;
}

#cats {
 text-align:center;
}

#cats li {list-style:none; margin:5px;}

#cats a {color:white; padding:8px; margin:5px; text-align:center; font-size:20px; text-decoration:none; font-family:Comic Sans Ms;}

#cats a:hover {color:orange; font-weight:bolder; text-decoration:underline;}



#items_box {
width:780px; 
text-align:center;
margin-left:30px;
margin-bottom:10px; 
}

 #single_item {float:left; margin-left:30px; padding:10px;}
 
 #single_item img {border:2px solid black;}
 
 #shopping_cart {width:800px; height:50px; background:black; color:white;}


#footer {
width:1000px;
height:100px;
background:gray;
clear:both;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<?php 
session_start();
include("functions/functions.php");

?>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>My Online Shop</title>
  
  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" media="all" /> 
 </head>
 
<body>
 
 <!--Main Container starts here-->
 <div class="wrapper_main">
 
  <!--Header starts here-->
  <div class="wrapper_header">
  
   <a href="index.php"><img id="logo" src="img/logo.gif" /> </a>
   <img id="banner" src="img/banner_ad.gif" />
  </div>
  <!--Header ends here-->
  
  <!--Navigation Bar starts-->
  <div class="menubar">
   
   <ul id="indexmenu">
    <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="all_products.php">All Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="customer/my_account.php">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="cart.php">Shopping Cart</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
   
   </ul>
   
   <div id="form">
    <form method="get" action="results.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="text" name="user_query" placeholder="Search a Product"/ > 
     <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
    </form>
   
   </div>
   
  </div>
  <!--Navigation Bar ends-->
 
  <!--Content wrapper starts-->
  <div class="content_wrapper">
  
   <div id="sidebar">
   
    <div id="sidebar_title">Categories</div>
    
    <ul id="cats">
    
    <?php getCategories(); ?>
    
                </ul>
     
    <div id="sidebar_title">Brands</div>
    
    <ul id="cats">
     
     <?php getBrandsName(); ?>
    
                </ul>
   
   
   </div>
  
   <div id="content_area">
   
                <div id="items_box">
                
                <?php getItem(); ?>
                
                </div>
   
            
  </div>
        </div>
                <!--Content wrapper ends-->
  
  
  
  <div id="footer">
  
  <h2 style="text-align:center; padding-top:30px;">&copy; 2018 </h2>
  
  </div>
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 </div> 
<!--Main Container ends here-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's all happening in the function `<?php getItem(); ?>` . Can you try to find the function in the project and add it to your question?

Comment: @StephenP Absolutely not, when the title of the question is "invalid or incomplete html syntax issue". That would be off-topic for Code Review.

Comment: I updated my answer. I found your missing </div>

Comment: after that line `<img src='admin_area/item_imgs/$item_image'width=180' height='180'/>` add this closing element -> `</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few first things regarding the HTML:

Change `<!DOCTYPE>` to `<!DOCTYPE html>`

in lin 38 change
`<input type="text" name="user_query" placeholder="Search a Product"/ >` to `<input type="text" name="user_query" placeholder="Search a Product" />`

you also have multiple usage of the id **cats** -> `id="cats"` . In HTML you can only have one ID per page. It has to unique.

---

and there is a `</div>` missing in the php function:

after that line `<img src='admin_area/item_imgs/$item_image'width=180' height='180'/>` add this closing element -> `</div>`

Comment: simon i've added my getItem function into the post. check it out

Comment: @OkeyDokey I found the missing </div>

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Simon's answer, it appears that you've missed clearing some floats. From what I can tell, `#sidebar` and `#content_area` have been left uncleared within `#content_area`. Adding a clear fix at the bottom of `#content_area` should fix things up. It's hard to tell with the content inside `#content_area` since you're developing locally and we don't have access to inspect that code.

Comment: hi kelly i'm not as familiar with front end as i am with backend. taking your suggestion, i have added clear:both to my content area #content_area {
width:800px;
float:right;
background:pink;
clear: both;
} .  but it's not working. how can i show u screenshot?

Comment: Hi, no worries. You don't need to apply clear: both; to #content_area. You need to either add <div style="clear: both;"></div> as the last element inside the #content_area div or add this to your CSS: #content_area:after {content: "";clear: both;display: block;height: 0px;} The second option is the more modern clearfix technique.

Comment: I think it was a missing closing </div>. I updated my answer. chekc it out

Comment: HI, i'm trying to avoid saying thank you as stackoverflow tells me that's a waste of time haha how rude, anyways the fix was a missing closing </div>. kelly you made me learn more about clearfixes than i have since i was born. i thank u for that. also simon thanks for the solution.

Comment: So it's not allowed to mark the answer as "correct" ? :D I am happy we found the bug ! Good luck with your project

Comment: Glad you got it!

Comment: Franzen i've got a problem with a table not populating. do u want me to edit the question again?